# React Router not changing sub page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my App.js i have a navbar and a router switch that takes me to admin page

```
 <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Welcome} />
          <AdminRoute path='/admin' component={Admin} />
```

My Admin component have a sub router as follows:

```
<Router>
    <SubNav />
    <Switch>
          <Route exact path={`${match.path}/planners`} component={Planners} />
          <Route exact path={`${match.path}/`} component = {Admin}>                
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

If i go to www.mysite/admin everything works fine and my SubNav links work fine. My issue is the my Navbar has links such as

```
 <Typography
              to='/admin/planners'
              component={Link}
            >
              Planners
            </Typography>
 <Typography
              to='/admin'
              component={Link}
            >
              Admin
            </Typography>
```

The moment i route to a subpage the Navbar links stop changing the subpages although they are changing the URL just fine. Linking from the Navbar at first time works then if i try clicking on Admin it does not route to / again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the `<Switch>` and removing the `<Router>` from the Admin component. `<Route>` alone without wrapping it with a `<Router>` was sufficient

Below is a code that explains the behavior

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Resource1({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Resource1</h3>
      <p>Resource1 Descriotion</p>
    </div>
  );
}
function Resource2({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Resource2</h3>
      <p>Resource2 Descriotion</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function Topic1({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Topic1</h2>
      <p>Topic1 Description</p>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/resource1`}>Resource 1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/resource2`}>Resource 2</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route path={`${match.path}/resource1`} component={Resource1} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/resource2`} component={Resource2} />
    </div>
  );
}
function Topic2({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Topic2</h2>
      <p>Topic2 Description</p>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/resource1`}>Resource 1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/resource2`}>Resource 2</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route path={`${match.path}/resource1`} component={Resource1} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/resource2`} component={Resource2} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Topics({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/topic1`}>Topic 1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/topic2`}>Topic 2</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route path={`${match.path}/topic1`} component={Topic1} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/topic2`} component={Topic2} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h1>Home</h1>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div style={{ width: 1000, margin: '0 auto' }}>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/topics'>Topics</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/topics/topic1/resource1'>Resource 1</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <hr />

          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/topics' component={Topics} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```